# Passing data from Activity to Fragment returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass some simple String data from my activity to my fragment. Here is my code:

Activity:

```
public class dashboard_view extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_view);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("title", "Charles Dickens' House");
        ItemFragment itemFragment = new ItemFragment();
        itemFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.dashboard, itemFragment).commit()
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
    // boilerplate code that Android studio added
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        plaqueTitle.setText(title);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
    }
}
```

When I compile my app, it compiles but then when it tries to run the app on the emulator, it crashes and the console shows an error message in the form of an exception. The root of the exception is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at ItemFragment.onCreateView(ItemFragment.java:73)
```

I assume this error is because the Bundle is not being picked up in the fragment, so it's calling `getString()` on nothing. However, I'm not sure how to get the Bundle to be passed through from the Activity to the Fragment.

EDIT: Add XML of Activity (I've added a fragment in there so you can see where I want it go).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tom.plaqueit.dashboard_view"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.tom.plaqueit.ItemFragment"
            android:id="@+id/plaque_fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you add ```itemFragment``` to your activity?

Comment: where and how do you show your fragment ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add some code in. I was using `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.dashboard, itemFragment).commit()` in the `onCreate` method in the Activity. I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Do you have an `ItemFragment` statically defined in the `activity_dashboard_view` layout?

Comment: @MikeM. I don't think I do, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Oh, no, you don't want to do that. That might've been the cause of your Exception, but if you don't have a `<fragment>` element in the layout, it's not that.

Comment: Where did initialize the plaqueTitle?

Comment: I'm not fixing the issue here, I just gotta point out the name of the class "dashboard_view" is hurting my eyes.

Comment: I think, it might be the problem of plaqueTitle

Comment: @Eric `plaqueTitle` is initialised in the ItemFragment class as a private variable, and then set as `(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.plaque_title);` in the `onViewCreated` method below `onCreateView`.

Comment: ok, did you call the onViewCreated before onCreateView?

Comment: @Eric doesn't matter the program crashes before it gets there. The program crashes because he is trying to execute getString on a null object.

Comment: @Eric I've just tried `plaqueTitle.setText("Hello World");` without the Bundle/Argument code and it threw an exception about `plaqueTitle` not being initialised, however as @noev said, it's crashing before that. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Where it says `.add(R.id.dashboard, itemFragment)`, dashboard is the `RelativeLayout` of my Activity. Is this correct?

Comment: If that's the empty ViewGroup you're using for the Fragment's container, then yeah. If it's the root View of the layout, or if it has child Views, probably not. We'd have to see the layout.

Comment: @MikeM I've added my XML layout to the post so you can take a look at the layout.

Comment: Your problem is the statically defined `<fragment>` in the layout, as I mentioned. A Fragment defined in the layout is loaded during the layout inflation occurring in the Activity's `setContentView()` method, and you never have a chance to set arguments on it, thus the NPE.  If you're not going to add any other Views to the layout, you can just remove that element, and your Transaction will load the Fragment dynamically.

Comment: Oh, wait. Is that the layout you're actually using? Or did you just add the `<fragment>` element for demonstration? I'm not sure what you mean in the parenthetical.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, so originally I had that fragment in the XML, and then started writing the code above to pass data into the fragment from the activity, and just left the fragment in the XML, thinking it wouldn't do any harm. I've removed that but I still get the NPE.

Comment: Did you rebuild the project? If so, and you're still getting the NPE, we'll need to see the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I need to go to bed now but thanks everyone for your help, I will continue this tomorrow :)

Comment: Just a quick note: if the top exception in your stacktrace is an `InflateException`, then that is most likely the problem. Rebuilding the project will refresh the build layouts, and should take care of it.

Comment: @MikeM. rebuilding the project seemed to take care of the error - I'd imagine it was as you thought - the statically generated fragment in the XML was causing the error - thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateView of your fragment, try not creating a new bundle object and just use:

```
String title = getArguments().getString("title");
```

That should work

Comment: Hi, that didn't work, sorry - same error. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize  plaqueTitle(TextView) before the **setText** action.

Comment: This doesn't change anything, because as I said in the comments above, I tried `plaqueTitle.setText("Hello World");` without the Bundle/Argument code and it threw a different exception about plaqueTitle not being initialised, which I now understand is because `onViewCreated` is called after `onCreateView` (where `plaqueTitle` is initialised). It is a problem though so thanks for making me aware of it :)

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is not the correct way to do this, but it works. Add a method to your fragment

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

Instead of bundle.putString("title", "Charles Dickens' House");

do

```
itemFragment.setTitle("Charles Dickens' House");
```

and now you can access your title from within the fragment.

Comment: Yeah that works but as you said, it's not ideal. I'll continue trying to find the proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I prefer this way as opposed to using the bundle because for more complex data types you don't have to implement the IParceable interface.